# How to remove duplicated rows from a dataframe `df` but only when a specific column of the `df` is NA?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a data frame `df` with 5 columns. `Region.Label` indicates the Region where the study was performed, `Sample.Label` is a specific area within that Region where I counted for birds, `Sp` is the bird species I found in that specific area, `Distance` is the distance between the bird and me, and `Effort` is the time I was in the area looking for birds. When `Distance` is `NA` means that for this area the species was not observed. As an example of the data frame I have:

```
df <- data.frame(Region.Label=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"),
                 Sample.Label=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3),
                 Sp=c("ZZ","ZZ","BB","ZZ","BB","CC","ZZ","BB"),
                 Distance=c(2,7,NA,NA,NA,6,NA,NA),
                 Effort=c(99,99,99,87,87,87,72,72))

df$Region.Label <- as.factor(df$Region.Label)
df$Sample.Label <- as.numeric(df$Sample.Label)
df

  Region.Label Sample.Label Sp Distance Effort
1            A            1 ZZ        2     99
2            A            1 ZZ        7     99
3            A            1 BB       NA     99
4            A            2 ZZ       NA     87
5            A            2 BB       NA     87
6            A            2 CC        6     87
7            A            3 ZZ       NA     72
8            A            3 BB       NA     72
```

Here, I would like to remove all the rows which have `NA` for the column `df$Distance`, as it indicates that the species was not observed in the area, but I want to delete rows with `NA` for `df$Distance` when that row with the `NA` is a duplicate of another row excluding the column `df$Sp`.

I would like to obtain this:

```
 Region.Label Sample.Label Sp Distance Effort
1            A            1 ZZ        2     99
2            A            1 ZZ        7     99
3            A            2 CC        6     87
4            A            3 ZZ       NA     72
```

In this example, I do not remove `df[7,]` because the `Sample.Label` is different from the previous rows. I remove `df[8,]` because `df[7,]` and `df[8,]` are equal except for `df$Sp`.

Does anyone know how to get what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, a group by operation would help - grouped by 'Region.Label', 'Sample.Label', 'Effort', `filter` the non-NA elements of 'Distance' if there are any non-NA elements or else get the first row (`row_number() == 1`)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 group_by(Region.Label, Sample.Label, Effort) %>% 
 filter(if(all(is.na(Distance))) row_number() == 1 else !is.na(Distance)) %>%
 ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  Region.Label Sample.Label Sp    Distance Effort
  <fct>               <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A                       1 ZZ           2     99
2 A                       1 ZZ           7     99
3 A                       2 CC           6     87
4 A                       3 ZZ          NA     72
```